# Change styles of radio container when radio is checked or hovered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to change the styles of 2 radio containers when the radio option has been clicked or hovered

```css
.gchoice_1_15_0, .gchoice_1_15_1 {
    width: 48%;
    color: #58595B;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
//Yes option
<div class="gchoice gchoice_1_15_0">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_15" type="radio" value="Yes" id="choice_1_15_0" onchange="/*gformToggleRadioOther( this )*/">
        <label for="choice_1_15_0" id="label_1_15_0">Yes</label>
</div>

//No option
<div class="gchoice gchoice_1_15_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_15" type="radio" value="No" id="choice_1_15_1" onchange="/*gformToggleRadioOther( this )*/">
        <label for="choice_1_15_1" id="label_1_15_1">No</label>
</div>
```

Once any of the options are checked or hovered I need to change the styles of the correct container:

If the "Yes" option is checked, change .gchoice_1_15_0 to

```
background: #EF8B22;
border: 1px solid #EF8B22;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgb(239 139 4 / 30%);
```

If the "No" option is checked, change .gchoice_1_15_1 to

```
background: #EF8B22;
border: 1px solid #EF8B22;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgb(239 139 4 / 30%);
```

I tried with this CSS but didn't work:

```
#choice_1_15_0:checked ~ .gchoice_1_15_0 {
    background: #EF8B22;
    border: 1px solid #EF8B22;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgb(239 139 4 / 30%);
}
```

How can I achieve that?

PD. HTML code can't be modified.

Comment: Use the `:checked` pseudo-class.

Comment: I did use the :checked pseudo-class but didn't work.

#choice_1_15_0:checked ~ .gchoice_1_15_0 { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem:

> I  tried with this CSS but didn't work:

- It doesn't work because CSS selectors are "forward-only".

  - The `~` and `+` combinators in CSS selectors cannot select an element based on a descendant element or next-sibling element's attributes or DOM state.
  - Conversely: It can only select elements based on their ancestor and previous-sibling elements' attributes and DOM state.
  - Indeed, the `+` combinator doesn't mean "adjacent sibling", [it means "*next* adjacent sibling"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), and `~` doesn't mean "any sibling", it means ["*any future siblings*"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).
- In your case: a CSS selector cannot use the `:checked` state of the `<input id="choice_1_15_0" />` when selecting `<div class="gchoice gchoice_1_15_0">`...

  - ...but CSS *can* use it to select `<label for="choice_1_15_0">`.

CSS selectors work this way for multiple reasons, the main one thing *performance*: the algorithm for applying CSS rules with these restrictive *forward-only* rules is much simpler and faster than if it had to support any kind of "look-backwards and upwards" rules.

That said, what I'm referring to is actually supported by web-browsers: [it's called the `:has()` relational selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), however because of those performance reasons [it isn't supported in CSS stylesheets](https://caniuse.com/css-has), only in in the DOM's `querySeletor` and `querySelectorAll` functions:

I note that since 2021, [some (non-Google) Chrome devs are
investigating ways to try to implement support for *limited kinds* of sub-selectors in `:has()` in Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5794378545102848), read about it here: https://css-has.glitch.me/ - but I doubt support for this will enter Chrome for years, let alone other browser engines like Safari and Firefox.

### Ideal solution: `:has()` selector:

If we could use `:has()`, then you could just do this and call it a day:

```
label[for]:has(input[type=radio]:checked) {
    background: #EF8B22;
    border: 1px solid #EF8B22;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgb(239 139 4 / 30%);
}
```

[Unfortunately they don't](https://caniuse.com/css-has), so we can't do this.

---

### Workaround: move your `<input/>` elements:

The workaround is to *hoist up* your `<input/>` to be located both above *and* before its container - but as you don't want the checkbox widget to be visually located there you'll need to either make the input invisible and use a replacement checkbox image in the `<label>` or use a CSS technique to relocate the rendered input element, perhaps using CSS `grid` or `flex` (or even `position`) but these don't give you much flexibility.

You can also use `::before` to add a fake checkbox/radio button (either using an aesthetically pleasing SVG or PNG as `background-image`, or use CSS `border` to render a box directly).

Something like this:

```css
input  { display: none; }
 
 .gchoice_1_15_0,
 .gchoice_1_15_1 {
      width: 48%;
      color: #58595B;
      border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding-left: 1em;
      background: #fff;
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      box-shadow: none;
}

#choice_1_15_0:checked ~ * label[for="choice_1_15_0"],
#choice_1_15_1:checked ~ * label[for="choice_1_15_1"] {
    background: #EF8B22;
    border: 1px solid #EF8B22;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgb(239 139 4 / 30%);
}

/* CSS-only radio buttons: */
label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: ' ';
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}

#choice_1_15_0:checked ~ * label[for="choice_1_15_0"]::before,
#choice_1_15_1:checked ~ * label[for="choice_1_15_1"]::before {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%);
}
```

```html
<input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_15" type="radio" value="Yes" id="choice_1_15_0" onchange="/*gformToggleRadioOther( this )*/">

<input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_15" type="radio" value="No" id="choice_1_15_1" onchange="/*gformToggleRadioOther( this )*/">

//Yes option
<div class="gchoice gchoice_1_15_0">
   <label for="choice_1_15_0" id="label_1_15_0">Yes</label>
</div>

//No option
<div class="gchoice gchoice_1_15_1">
    <label for="choice_1_15_1" id="label_1_15_1">No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The HTML can't be modified. Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for without modifying the HTML?

Comment: @HenryMendez If you want natively-styled inputs then no - but if you have your own checkbox images then just restyle the labels. Or wait about a decade for browsers to finally support `:has()` in stylesheets

Comment: That's too bad. I thought It could be possible with CSS only. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.